# How do Hadoop ChainMapper and ChainReducer reduce disk IO

Tags: hadoop

I want to chain multiple mapreduce jobs i.e. previous mapreduce job's output is the input of next mapreduce job. Because my output is very large and disk IO overload is very heavy, I would like to find alternative solution to reduce IO bottleneck. I found ChainMapper/ChainReducer API. The document mentioned the following properties

"Using the ChainMapper and the ChainReducer classes is possible to compose Map/Reduce jobs that look like [MAP+ / REDUCE MAP*]. And immediate benefit of this pattern is a dramatic reduction in disk IO."

But I don't quite understand why using ChainMapper/ChainReducer will reduce disk IO. And to reduce IO, how should I use these two APIs?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, even though you have multiple mappers, chain mapper considers them as single task.Till the task complete,there is no intermediate write.

See the below statement from javadoc.

The Mapper classes are invoked in a chained (or piped) fashion, the output of the first becomes the input of the second, and so on until the last Mapper, the output of the last Mapper will be written to the task's output.